# .NET Active Directory Password Expiration on Windows 2008

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, windows-server-2008, passwords

Searched SO and Everywhere else, including the .net developers guide to directory services programming book - no luck.

I am trying to create a simple password reset web page that allows the user to change their password.  The change password portion of the code is working fine.  For the users I would also like to display when their current password will expire next.

Using the sample code from the book mentioned above I was able to get all of the code setup however, the attribute that is returned is always equal to Long.MinValue and hence cannot be inverted to a positive number, plus this means it did not find the proper domain setting.

Does anyone have sample code or references for getting the password expiration in a Windows 2008 or R2 domain environment where password policies can be different for each user?

**Updated to include code**

Constructor that gets the policy object:

```
public PasswordExpires()
    {
        //Get Password Expiration
        Domain domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
        DirectoryEntry root = domain.GetDirectoryEntry();

        using (domain)
        using (root)
        {
            this.policy = new DomainPolicy(root);
        }
    }
```

Domain Policy Constructor:

```
public DomainPolicy(DirectoryEntry domainRoot)
    {
        string[] policyAttributes = new string[] {
  "maxPwdAge", "minPwdAge", "minPwdLength", 
  "lockoutDuration", "lockOutObservationWindow", 
  "lockoutThreshold", "pwdProperties", 
  "pwdHistoryLength", "objectClass", 
  "distinguishedName"
  };

        //we take advantage of the marshaling with
        //DirectorySearcher for LargeInteger values...
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(
          domainRoot,
          "(objectClass=domainDNS)",
          policyAttributes,
          SearchScope.Base
          );

        SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();

        //do some quick validation...         
        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
              "domainRoot is not a domainDNS object."
              );
        }

        this.attribs = result.Properties;
    }
```

Call this method to get the password expiration:

```
public TimeSpan MaxPasswordAge
    {
        get
        {
            string val = "maxPwdAge";
            if (this.attribs.Contains(val))
            {
                long ticks = GetAbsValue(
                  this.attribs[val][0]
                  );

                if (ticks > 0)
                    return TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks);
            }

            return TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        }
    }
```

Code fails here because it cannot convert Long.MinValue, which it should not be in the first place

```
private long GetAbsValue(object longInt)
    {
        return Math.Abs((long)longInt);
    }
```

Here is the debugger output and values.  According to the MSDN Site the overflow exception is caused from the minvalue.  My numbers match the examples for minvalue.

[Screenshot http://www.brentpabst.com/capture.png](http://www.brentpabst.com/capture.png)

Comment: Password expiration is a group policy thing, isn't it?

Comment: @gabe Updated it to inlude the code. Anything you have is helpful.

@zneak it's managed through group policy but is exposed through LDAP and other mechanisms

Comment: How do you know it fails due to getting `long.MinValue`?

Comment: And why would you do an `Abs` on it anyway? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @gabe I added a link to the debugger screenshot to show you the value and the exception.  I followed the example from the book referenced where they invert the values because they claim they are stored as negative numbers.  I am expecting a number much smaller like 1061029 not the huge long one.  I don't know enough about how AD stores the attribute to tell you why it would be negative, hence the reference book.

Comment: Maybe the your passwords are set to not expire. Can you see what a tool like `adfind`, `ldife`, or `ldp` tells you for that property?

Comment: @gabe I'm an idiot.  I had changed the test domain settings earlier to work with a different setting. After updating the GPO and pushing it out things appear to be resolved.  Do you know if there are specific things you have to plan for when looking at a 2008 controller as opposed to an older controller because of how the policies are distributed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password expiration times are stored such that if `lastPwdSet - maxPwdAge < DateTime.UtcNow` is true, then your password is expired. So if you set your password a week ago, but the password will expire in 10 days, the left side will be `(DateTime.UtcNow - 7) - (-10)`, or `DateTime.UtcNow - 7 + 10`, or `DateTime.UtcNow + 3`, which is not less than `DateTime.UtcNow`, so your password won't be expired.

This means that setting maxPwdAge to long.MinValue will effectively give you thousands of years before your password expires. So if you are getting `long.MinValue`, your policy says that passwords won't expire. You should just look for that value and treat it properly, possibly like this:

```
private long GetAbsValue(object longInt)  // poorly named
{
    long val = (long)longInt;
    if (val == long.MinValue)
        return long.MaxValue;
    return Math.Abs((long)longInt);  
}
```

Also, I should point out that the values are stored in 100-nanosecond increments, so you should expect values in the billions.